# Adding copy of row to "almost normalized" matrix does not change $X^\top X$ product

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Good evening, I have a hard time with the following problem, I found how to start, but don't see how to continue:
Imagine we have a $D$x$N$ matrix $X$ such that all rows are normalized (zero mean and variance one), except for the last row, that has variance 2. Suppose that we also have a second matrix, say $\tilde{X}$, which is defined as a $(D+1)$x$N$ matrix with the same rows as X, except row $D$ is now normalized, and row $D + 1$ is a copy of row $D$.

So to summarize, $X$ is almost normalized, only last row has variance 2 and $\tilde{X}$ is perfectly normalized, but has two equal rows. Now I have to show that $X^\top X = \tilde{X}^\top\tilde{X}$.

I started by writting $\tilde{X}$ as $KX$ where K is a $(D+1)$x$D$ matrix with the first $D$ rows forming an identity matrix, and the last row being $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} * \textbf{e}_n$ where $\textbf{e}_n$ is the unit vector with a 1 in position n and zeros everywhere else, so that we have a normalized row in $\tilde{X}$. After that, I still cannot show the result...

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is a matrix with rows $r_1,r_2,\dots,r_D$ (each of size $1 \times N$). We have
$$
X^\top X = \sum_{i=1}^D r_i^\top r_i = r_D^\top r_D + \sum_{i=1}^{D-1}r_i^\top r_i.
$$
Now, the modified matrix $\tilde X$ has the same rows except that the final row $r_D$ is replaced with the normalized $\tilde r_D = r_D/\sqrt{2}$ and a row $\tilde r_{D+1} = \tilde r_D$ is added. We then find that
$$
\begin{align}
{\tilde X}^\top \tilde X &= \tilde r_{D+1}^\top \tilde r_{D+1} + \tilde r_D^\top \tilde r_D + \sum_{i=1}^{D-1}r_i^\top r_i
\\ & = 
[r_D/\sqrt{2}]^\top [r_D/\sqrt{2}] + [r_D/\sqrt{2}]^\top [r_D/\sqrt{2}] + 
\sum_{i=1}^{D-1}r_i^\top r_i
\\ & = 
\frac 12 r_D^\top r_D + \frac 12 r_D^\top r_D + \sum_{i=1}^{D-1}r_ir_i^\top
\\ & = r_D^\top r_D + \sum_{i=1}^{D-1} r_i^\top r_i = X^\top X.
\end{align}
$$

---

Alternatively, note that we can write $\tilde X = RX$, where
$$
R = \pmatrix{
I_{(D-1) \times (D - 1)} & 0_{(D - 1) \times 1}\\ 
0_{1 \times (D-1)} & 1/\sqrt{2}\\
0_{1 \times (D-1)} & 1/\sqrt{2}}.
$$
Verify that $R^\top R = I$, so that
$$
[\tilde X]^\top [\tilde X] = [RX]^\top [RX] = 
X^\top R^\top R X = X^\top I X = X^\top X.
$$

Comment: I am sorry, I don't see how you go from $X^\top X$ to $\sum_{i = 1}^D r_i^\top r_i$ thanks a lot for your help...

Comment: @Alf Use block-matrix multiplication. Note that
$$
X^\top X = \pmatrix{r_1^\top & \cdots & r_D^\top} \pmatrix{r_1\\ \vdots \\ r_D}.
$$
I've also added an alternative proof.

Comment: Thanks for the second proof, that is what I was trying to do, but could not achieve